# Output for nested list comprehension as empty list instead of list with None

Tags: python

I have a nested list which I am trying to parse into datetime objects.
Some strings have invalid formats which should be an empty list in the output.

```
input = [
   ['20210804:1700', '20210805:1600'],
   ['20210805:1700', '20210806:1600'],
   ['20210807:CLOSED']]
```

So far I have the following.

```
def _helper(x):
    try:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d:%H%M')
    except Exception:
        return

output = [[_helper(i) for i in group] for group in input]
```

Currently the output is as follows

```
[[datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 4, 17, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 16, 0)],
[datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 17, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 16, 0)], 
[None]]
```

I would like the output to have an empty list `[]` instead of `[None]`.
How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: You can try `output = [list(filter(bool, map(_helper, i))) for i in input]`

Answer (score 0):

```
output = [[_helper(i) for i in group if _helper(i) is not None] for group in input]
```

Comment: If ```_helper(i)``` was computationally expensive to run wouldn't this greatly increase the runtime?

Answer (score 0):

```
from nltk.util import flatten

def _helper(x):
    try:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d:%H%M')
    except Exception:
        return []

output = [flatten([_helper(i) for i in group]) for group in input]
```

Comment: This would replace `[None]` with `[[]]`

Comment: fair enough cheers, added flatten to mitigate that

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested list comprehension to filter out `None` values from the generated list.

```py
import datetime as dt

input = [
    ['20210804:1700', '20210805:1600'],
    ['20210805:1700', '20210806:1600'],
    ['20210807:CLOSED']]


def _helper(x):
    try:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d:%H%M')
    except Exception:
        return


output = [[x for x in [_helper(i) for i in group] if x is not None]
          for group in input]

print(output)
```

Outputs...

```py
[
  [datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 4, 17, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 16, 0)], 
  [datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 17, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 16, 0)], 
  []
]
```